# Nautilus / Files policy change or bug in Recent files?

Tags: nautilus, files, 19.04

Since updating to 19.04 a lot of files that used to show up in Recent are no longer showing up (ie downloads), and I have to search around to find them.

I've done some searching but have not found anything that explains this.

Do you know if this is the result of a policy change or something is broken?

If broken, can you help me fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: In Settings - Privacy, check if "Usage and history" is checked. It works correctly for me, and also I have a system that is been updated from a previous version, and not freshly installed.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks, it was checked.